# akka-http does not add Remote-Address in request headers

Tags: scala, akka-http

According to akka-http [extractClientIP](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/docs/src/main/paradox/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/misc-directives/extractClientIP.md) and [Documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.5/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/misc-directives/extractClientIP.html):

> The akka-http server engine adds the Remote-Address header to every
>   request automatically if the respective setting
>   akka.http.server.remote-address-header is set to on. Per default it is
>   set to off.

The application.conf has been set accordingly

```
akka {
  http {
    server {
      remote-address-header = on
    }
  }
}
```

The test below failed to extract `Remote-Address` from the request headers

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
import akka.http.scaladsl.client.RequestBuilding
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.http.scaladsl.testkit.ScalatestRouteTest

"Remote-Address added to request header by akka-http" in {
  val request = RequestBuilding.Get("/").withHeaders(`User-Agent`(this.getClass.getSimpleName))
  val miniRoute: Route = { ctx => ctx.complete("Always Succeed") }

  request ~> miniRoute ~> check {
    assert(responseAs[String] == "Always Succeed")
  }

  //confirm akka config setting is correct
  assert(ConfigFactory.load().getString("akka.http.server.remote-address-header") == "on", "FAILED: please set application.conf: akka.http.server.remote-address-header = on")

  val remoteIP: Option[HttpHeader] = request.headers.find(_.name == "Remote-Address")
  assert(remoteIP.nonEmpty, "FAILED: Remote-Address missing in Request Headers")
}
```

**Question** Should akka-http inject **automatically** `Remote-Address` in the request headers? Also I'd appreciate if you can show how to rewrite this test where the `akka.http.server.remote-address-header` config can be set programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're facing this issue because testkit's `ScalatestRouteTest` does not perform the automatic addition of the `Remote-Address`. It only happens at the `Http()` object level (see [source](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http-core/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/Http.scala#L126) for more details).

If you want to see it in action, you can spin up a server running

```
object Tmp extends App {
  implicit val sys = ActorSystem("tmp")
  implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()

  val route = headerValueByName("Remote-Address") { complete(_) }

  Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)
}
```

and depending on your configuration (which is correct in your question) you should get either `200 OK` (if setting is `on`) or `400 Bad Request` (if setting is `off`).

Answer (score 1):

Following your advice, I made the test below which is working as expected. Hope this would be useful to someone else.

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.{HeaderDirectives, RouteDirectives}
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

/** Verify that akka-http engine injects the "Remote-Address" header in the request headers
  * if the config key "akka.http.server.remote-address-header = on"
  *
  * TESTING (set config on/off via command line argument)
  * 1. Run the mini web server
  *    sbt "runMain blabla.AkkaRemoteAddressTest on"
  *
  * 2. Open Git-Bash and type:
  *    $ curl -s http://localhost:2017
  *      (console output) Remote-Address = 127.0.0.1:58208 (Thursday, 02 Mar 2017 - 18:54:55)
  *    $ curl -s http://$COMPUTERNAME:2017
  *      (console output) Remote-Address = 10.5.34.101:58285 (Thursday, 02 Mar 2017 - 18:57:30)
  */
object AkkaRemoteAddressTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val configValue =
      if (args.isEmpty) "on"
      else if (args(0).toLowerCase != "on" && args(0).toLowerCase != "off") "on"
      else args(0)

    val miniConfig = ConfigFactory.parseString(
      s"""
        |akka.http.server.remote-address-header = $configValue
      """.stripMargin)

    implicit val sys = ActorSystem("AkkaRemoteAddressTest", miniConfig)
    implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()

    val sdfmt = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMM yyyy - HH:mm:ss")

    val route = HeaderDirectives.headerValueByName("Remote-Address") {
      remaddr => RouteDirectives.complete(s"Remote-Address = $remaddr (${sdfmt.format(java.util.Calendar.getInstance.getTime)})")
    }

    Http().bindAndHandle(route, "0.0.0.0", 2017)
  }
}
```